# stm32f429, spi dr register not write data

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

[code_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci9p6.png)

[code_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZcGs.png)

[register on debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAqv9.png)

[logic analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z17iT.png)

void SPI_SendData(SPI_RegDef_t *pSPIx,uint8_t *pTxBuffer , uint32_t Len)
{

```
while(Len > 0)
{

    // 1 . wait until TXE is set ,
    while(SPI_GetFlagStatus(pSPIx, SPI_TXE_FLAG) == FLAG_RESET);

    // 2. check the DFF bit in CR1
    if( (pSPIx->CR1 & (1 << SPI_CR1_DFF) ) )
    {
        // 16 BIT DFF
        pSPIx->DR = *((uint16_t*)pTxBuffer); // dereferencing(typecasting );
        Len--;
        Len--;
        (uint16_t*)pTxBuffer++; // typecasting this pointer to uint16 type and incrementing by 2.
        /* The buffer is a uint8_t pointer type. When using the 16-bit data frame,
         * we pick up 16-bits of data, increment pointer by 2 bytes,*/
    }else
    {

        // 8 BIT DFF
         pSPIx->DR = *pTxBuffer;
        Len--;
        pTxBuffer++;
        /*
         *(( uint8_t*)&hspi->Instance->DR) = (*pData);
            pData += sizeof(uint8_t);
            hspi->TxXferCount--;

         */
    }

}
```

}

i see, MOSI always send 255  on logic analyzer but wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

`(uint16_t*)pTxBuffer++;` increments the pointer by 1 byte, not two that you say you hope it will in the comment.

If you want to do it by converting to halfword pointer and incrementing, then you need to do something like:

```
pTxBuffer = (uint8_t*)(((uint16_t*)pTxBuffer) + 1);
```

But that is just a silly way of saying `pTxBuffer += 2;`

Really it doesn't make sense to have the if inside the loop, because the value of the DFF bit doesn't change unless you write to it, and you don't.  I suggest you write one loop over words and one loop over bytes and have the if at the top level.